# Singleton with NSArray of Core data objects null

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, singleton

So I have a Singleton that holds a NSArray. This array gets initiated with 120K+ objects from a core data fetch request. When I go to access these objects in my view controller via the array they are null. It shows the correct number of objects, and they show up fine inside the singleton after the initialization. Any thoughts? Thank you for the help.

**Singleton.h**

```
@interface Singleton : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *singletonArray;
+(Singleton*)singleton;
@end
```

**Singleton.m**

```
#import "Singleton.h"
#import "DataAccessLayer.h"

@implementation Singleton
@synthesize singletonArray;
+(Singleton *)singleton {
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static __strong Singleton *shared = nil;
    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        shared = [[Singleton alloc]init]; 
    });
    return shared;
}

-(id)init 
{
    if (self = [super init]) 
    {
        DataAccessLayer *dataAccess = [[DataAccessLayer alloc]init];
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyEntity" inManagedObjectContext: dataAccess.managedObjectContext]];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES]]];
        NSError *error = nil;
        self.singletonArray = [dataAccess.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Singleton.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad]; 
    FAKFontAwesome *settingsIcon = [FAKFontAwesome gearIconWithSize:22];
    [settingsIcon addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    UIImage *settingsIconImage = [settingsIcon imageWithSize:CGSizeMake(22, 22)];

    UIButton *settingsIconButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 22, 22)];
    [settingsIconButton addTarget:self action:@selector(settingsBarButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [settingsIconButton setImage:settingsIconImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.settingsBarButton setCustomView:settingsIconButton];

    self.masterArray = [NSArray new];
    self.masterArray = [[Singleton singleton] singletonArray];

    NSString *title = [[self.masterArray objectAtIndex:0] field1];
    NSLog(@"Viewdidload: %@", title);
}

- (IBAction)settingsBarButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSString *title = [[self.masterArray objectAtIndex:0] field1];
    NSLog(@"SettingsBarButtonClicked Log %@", title);
}

@end
```

**Console Output In Singleton**

```
(lldb) po [self.singletonArray count]
120441

(lldb) po [self.singletonArray objectAtIndex:0]
<MyEntity: 0x14c0628c0> (entity: MyEntity; id: 0xd00000070e740000 <x-coredata://8DAFE4F5-7218-4F6F-B32A-1BD9C056D1B9/MyEntity/p115613> ; data: {
    "field1" = "joe";
    "field2" = "doe";
})
```

**Console Output In ViewController**

```
 2015-11-19 17:51:09.188 MyApp[20299:7909725] Viewdidload: joe

 2015-11-19 17:54:36.637 MyApp[20334:7913246] SettingsBarButtonClicked Log (null)

(lldb) po [self.masterArray count]
120441

(lldb) po [self.masterArray objectAtIndex:0]
<MyEntity: 0x1366db7a0> (entity: <null>; id: 0xd00000070e740000 <x-coredata://8DAFE4F5-7218-4F6F-B32A-1BD9C056D1B9/MyEntity/p115613> ; data: <fault>)
```

Comment: If you look at the output of the second ’po` you can see that the object is a `fault`; this means that core data will retrieve the actual object the first time it is accessed. Have you tried accessing one of the properties?

Comment: Why aren't you setting a batch size on the fetch? And show the view controller code.

Comment: I updated the code to show the view controller and logs. One thing I did notice is there is a large memory spike when the singleton is called in the view did load, up to about 145mb. Then after that it drops to about 40mb. Could ARC be cleaning up the singleton or the core data content somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that fetching all records and storing them in an array in memory is a really bad idea. Basically, it defeats the purpose of the database.

I recommend to use a `NSFetchedResultsController` to access your objects instead. You will get so much for free: great performance, memory optimization and many other features, e.g. for updating your your list as new data is saved, or for populating a table view etc.

*NB: from your question it seems that the array is read just fine. Try to log the content of the actual "field1" of your entity and check if it works.*

Comment: I believe the issue with using a Singleton with this much data was a memory issue. I ended up creating a global fetchRequest method that I pass predicate key and values. This allows me to receive filtered arrays based on a field and value. Thank you for the suggestion